# Cannot find Android Build Tools 23.0.1 with React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I have Android Build Tools 23.0.1 installed in my Android SDK. I run this command:

> android list sdk -a | grep Build

And find this output:

> 3- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 25
>      4- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24.0.3
>      5- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24.0.2
>      6- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24.0.1
>      7- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24
>      8- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.3
>      9- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.2
>     10- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
>     11- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23 (Obsolete)
>     12- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22.0.1
>     13- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22 (Obsolete)
>     14- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2
>     15- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.1 (Obsolete)
>     16- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1 (Obsolete)
>     17- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.2 (Obsolete)
>     18- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.1 (Obsolete)
>     19- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21 (Obsolete)
>     20- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 20
>     21- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
>     22- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3 (Obsolete)
>     23- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2 (Obsolete)
>     24- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1 (Obsolete)
>     25- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19 (Obsolete)
>     26- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1 (Obsolete)
>     27- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1 (Obsolete)
>     28- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1 (Obsolete)
>     29- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17 (Obsolete)

Yet the error I get when trying to `react-native run-android` is:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   > failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1

What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you try to build the android app with Android Studio which can fix some issue automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Even if the list displays the build tools and you updated your SDK with the non-interative console command, the Build Tools are not automatically downloaded, and the list does not reflect whether the tools are installed or not. In my case, the build tools for that version were not installed.